# Can't use my form

Tags: zend-framework

I have class with my form in folder /application/forms/Auth.php
it looks like

```
class Form_Auth extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setName();
        parent::__construct();

        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $mail = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('mail');
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');

        $this->addElements(array($username,$password,$mail,$submit));
    }
}
```

When i try create object

```
$this->view->form = new Form_Auth();
```

is see exeption

> Application error
>
> Exception information:
>
> Message: Invalid name provided; must
>   contain only valid variable characters
>   and be non-empty
>
> Stack trace:
>
> D:\WWW\zends\application\Forms\Auth.php(8):
>   Zend_Form->setName()
>   d:\WWW\zends\application\controllers\RegistrationController.php(49):
>   Form_Auth->__construct()
>   D:\WebServer\ZendFramework\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513):
>   RegistrationController->indexAction()
>   D:\WebServer\ZendFramework\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(289):
>   Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
>   D:\WebServer\ZendFramework\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954):
>   Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
>   Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
>   D:\WebServer\ZendFramework\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97):
>   Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
>   D:\WebServer\ZendFramework\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application.php(366):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
>   D:\WWW\zends\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
>   {main}   Request Parameters:
>
> array (   'controller' =>
>   'registration',   'action' => 'index',
>   'module' => 'default', )

the version zf is 1.10.3

what i do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

We also managed this->setName('most have some name')